# Android: Unable to display SQLlite data and display on custom listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I encountered problem when trying to display data from SQLlite db and show on custom list view with 3textviews and 1 toggle button

Main Activity:

```
public class PaymentReminderActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ReminderDataSource datasource;
ReminderClass[] reminderObject;
ReminderClass reminder;
// Array of booleans to store toggle button status
public boolean[] status;
ListView lvReminder;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment_reminder);


    reminderObject = new ReminderClass[10000];
    reminder = new ReminderClass();
    datasource = new ReminderDataSource(this);
    //GET ALL DATA
    datasource.open();


    final List<ReminderClass> values = datasource.getAllUsers();

    if(values.isEmpty()!=false) {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            reminder = values.get(i);
            reminderObject[i].setType(reminder.getType());
            reminderObject[i].setDesc(reminder.getDesc());
            reminderObject[i].setDay(reminder.getDay());
        }
    }

    datasource.close();

    /** Restore from the previous state if exists */
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        status = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray("status");
    }

    lvReminder = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
    registerForContextMenu(lvReminder);

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lv, View item, int position, long id) {

            ListView lView = (ListView) lv;

            SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) lView.getAdapter();

            HashMap<String,Object> hm = (HashMap) adapter.getItem(position);

            /** The clicked Item in the ListView */
            RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) item;

            /** Getting the toggle button corresponding to the clicked item */

            ToggleButton tgl = (ToggleButton) rLayout.getChildAt(2);

            String strStatus = "";
            if(tgl.isChecked()){
                tgl.setChecked(false);
                strStatus = "Off";
                status[position]=false;
            }else{
                tgl.setChecked(true);
                strStatus = "On";
                status[position]=true;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), (String) hm.get("txt") + " : " + strStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    lvReminder.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

    List<HashMap<String,Object>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

  //  if(reminderObject!=null) {
        for (int i = 0; reminderObject[i+1]!=null ; i++) {
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put("txt", reminderObject[i].getType());
            hm.put("txt2", reminderObject[i].getDesc());
            hm.put("txt3", reminderObject[i].getDay()+" of every month");
            hm.put("stat", status[i]);
            aList.add(hm);
        }
  //  }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = {"txt","txt2","txt3","stat" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.tv_item,R.id.tv_item2, R.id.tv_item3, R.id.tgl_status};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);

    lvReminder.setAdapter(adapter);
}

/** Saving the current state of the activity
 * for configuration changes [ Portrait <=> Landscape ]
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBooleanArray("status", status);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_payment_reminder, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_add) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, NewReminderActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (v.getId()==R.id.lv_countries) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    long selectid = info.id; //_id from database in this case
    int selectpos = info.position;
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add:
            // add stuff here
            return true;
        case R.id.edit:
            // edit stuff here
            return true;
        case R.id.delete:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

This is the layout xml file of the custom listview
lvlayout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_item2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_item"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/tgl_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_item3"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/tv_item3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_item2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

there is an error at logcat, null pointer exception which points the error at this part of code, at beginning of onCreate method:

```
final List<ReminderClass> values = datasource.getAllUsers();
if(values.isEmpty()!=false) {
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
reminder = values.get(i);
reminderObject[i].setType(reminder.getType());
reminderObject[i].setDesc(reminder.getDesc());
reminderObject[i].setDay(reminder.getDay());
}
}
```

Datasourse file:

```
public class ReminderDataSource {
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private ReminderSQLHelper dbHelper;
private String[] allColumn = {
        Reminder.COLUMN_TYPE,
        Reminder.COLUMN_DESC,
        Reminder.COLUMN_DAY
};
public ReminderDataSource(Context context){

    dbHelper = new ReminderSQLHelper(context);
}
public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
public void close(){
    dbHelper.close();
}


public void insertRecord(ReminderClass reminder){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Reminder.COLUMN_TYPE, reminder.getType());
    values.put(Reminder.COLUMN_DESC, reminder.getDesc());
    values.put(Reminder.COLUMN_DAY, reminder.getDay());
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    database.insert(Reminder.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    database.close();
}


public List<ReminderClass> getAllUsers() {
    List<ReminderClass> records = new ArrayList<ReminderClass>();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(Reminder.TABLE_NAME, allColumn, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        ReminderClass reminder = new ReminderClass();
        reminder.setType(cursor.getString(0));
        reminder.setDesc(cursor.getString(1));
        reminder.setDay(cursor.getString(2));
        records.add(reminder);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return records;
}
```

}

Thank you. i appreciate for your help

Comment: ps : i tried debug, it have successfully retrieve information from sqllite, but it doesnt show out in the listview when running the app.

Comment: doesn't show... any error? if yes post logcat

Comment: logcat is too long. but there is an error "null pointer exception" which point to this part of code

    final List<ReminderClass> values = datasource.getAllUsers();

    if(values.isEmpty()!=false) {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            reminder = values.get(i);
            reminderObject[i].setType(reminder.getType());
            reminderObject[i].setDesc(reminder.getDesc());
            reminderObject[i].setDay(reminder.getDay());
        }
    }

Comment: logcat is pointing to which line? what is the code in that line?

Comment: edited at my question. thanks

Comment: is this class `datasource` activity class?

Comment: no. it is a class for accessing database with insert(), getAll() methods

Comment: What I mean to ask is its a database class where you need to pass the context as the parameter? may be thats where you are getting null.

Comment: i edited my question with the datasource class.. please help me have a look.. thanks

Comment: try the below solution and let me know the result

Answer (score 0):

ok try this:

```
reminderObject = new ReminderClass[10000];
    reminder = new ReminderClass();
//    datasource = new ReminderDataSource(this); //remove this
    //GET ALL DATA
    datasource.open();


    final List<ReminderClass> values = datasource(getApplicationContext()).getAllUsers();

    if(values.isEmpty()!=false) {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            reminder = values.get(i);
            reminderObject[i].setType(reminder.getType());
            reminderObject[i].setDesc(reminder.getDesc());
            reminderObject[i].setDay(reminder.getDay());
        }
    }
```

Comment: datasource(getApplicationContext())
is redunderlined, when i move my mouse cursor over it, it shows "method call expected"

Comment: Remove that and just press control enter and take select application context from drop down